# So who won the 2012 moderator elections?

Tags: discussion, election

I have participated in and watched the nomination/election process of our site recently. But now that the election is over, all traces of links to it are gone. It leaves me wondering, "Who won?" I even checked out the "about" link to see our moderators and they were not listed with the new moderators.

Is there a way to find out? I was hoping there would be an announcement or something. Anything. Perhaps in the future we could leave the link to the election running a bit longer and/or even post results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those interested in the election results...

```
OpenSTV version 1.7 (http://www.OpenSTV.org/)

Suggested donation for using OpenSTV for an election is $50.  Please go to 
http://www.OpenSTV.org/donate to donate via PayPal, Google Checkout, or
Amazon Payments.  

Certified election reports are also available.  Please go to 
http://www.openstv.org/certified-reports for more information.

Loading ballots from file dba-stackexchange-com-2012-election-results.blt.
Ballot file contains 4 candidates and 87 ballots.
No candidates have withdrawn.
Ballot file contains 87 non-empty ballots.

Counting votes for Database Administrators Moderator Election 2012 using Scottish STV.
4 candidates running for 1 seat.

 R|JNK          |Nick Chammas |ConcernedOfTu|Eric Higgins |Exhausted    |Surplus      |Threshold    
  |             |             |nbridgeWells |             |             |             |             
====================================================================================================
 1|     24.00000|     40.00000|     20.00000|      3.00000|      0.00000|      0.00000|     44.00000
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count of first choices. No candidates have surplus votes so candidates will be eliminated and
  | their votes transferred for the next round.
====================================================================================================
 2|     27.00000|     40.00000|     20.00000|             |      0.00000|      0.00000|     44.00000
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Eric Higgins and transferring votes. No candidates have surplus votes so
  | candidates will be eliminated and their votes transferred for the next round.
====================================================================================================
 3|     37.00000|     50.00000|             |             |      0.00000|      6.00000|     44.00000
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells and transferring votes. Candidate Nick Chammas
  | has reached the threshold and is elected.

Winner is Nick Chammas.
```

This is assuming I have the right settings (Scottish STV and San Francisco)

Since Nick [withdrew from the election](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4692160#4692160), the runner-up, JNK, is the new moderator. Congrats JNK! :)

Comment: BTW: You had the right settings, and we had word that Nick asked to step out of the running pre-election-finale, but post-election-start. As we can all see from the last line (3) JNK was the only runner-up of contention, so he wins.

Answer (score 15):

I sincerely apologize for the delay in wrapping up the moderator elections.  I've been sick this week and this didn't get picked up.

Congratulations to JNK on becoming our newest mod! (:

The [election page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/election/2) has been updated to reflect this.

Comment: why did you frown? Doh!

Comment: Could we do a banner announcement? Like what we do when we announce the elections in the first place? Otherwise it is hard to find the elections page to find the results.

Comment: @ChrisAldrich check out the community bulletin in the sidebar.  This question appears there. (:

Comment: I see it. Was just hoping to have a banner announcement or something more visible. :(

Answer (score 8):

According to the ballot file from the [election page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/election/2), [Nick Chammas](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2660/nick-chammas) is the winner. However, as mentioned in the comments, it seems like he'll be unable to step in as moderator. Based on this, it's likely that the runner-up, [JNK](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1945/jnk), is your new moderator.  I'm not sure why the page doesn't indicate that at the moment, though it probably has something to do with this situation.

As far as the about page goes, moderators have to go through a bit of an orientation process before receiving their privileges and therefore won't appear on that page until after they're officially given their diamond.

Comment: [He mentioned in chat last night](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4692160#4692160) he won't be able to accept for an undisclosed reason.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. I'm unsure what happens in situations like this...as it turns out, withdrawing him from the ballot would make you the electee (and his chat message suggests that's the plan, it seems)

Comment: I spoke to Robert Cartaino and Aarthi Devanathan over email about withdrawing. They reassured me that the election process would be unaffected as they would just select the first runner-up to be moderator if I won.

Comment: @NickChammas Great, thanks for the confirmation. Also, sorry to hear that you'll be unable to claim your diamond, but I'm happy to hear that it sounds like it's for positive reasons!

Comment: @TimStone - are we going to have an official announcement? I just wonder because we do a great job of announcing elections, but then it seems we leave up to the community to figure out the results, rather than announcing it and communicating it as well. I see now the posting on the election page about the results. But I guess I couldn't easily find how to GET to the election page in the first place. I guess what I'm really asking for its better/more visible communication about this.